# jQueryUI tab/menu synergy (forcing inactive tab to appear active)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I understand the frivolous nature of this problem, but it is a requirement of my client.

On my page I have a vertical menu that loads pages

There is some static content in a div at the top

And dynamic content in a tabbed pane below.  This dynamic content is 2 tables that are reloaded with ajax when each vertical menu item is selected.  So the div is not reloaded only the content of those tables.

The purpose of the tabs are to mimic the vertical menu while making this div appear to be a tabbed pane, which I have already implemented.   See below:

```
________________________________________________________________
|vetical|                                                      |
| menu  |                 Static Content                       |
|       |------------------------------------------------------|
|       | [TAB][TAB][TAB]                                      |
|       | -----------------------------------------            |
|       | :                                       :            |
|       | :    Dynamic Content                    :            |
|       | :                                       :            |
|       | :                                       :            |
|_______|_:_______________________________________:____________|
```

My issue is this.  When a tab is inactive and I select an item on the vertical menu.  How can I make it appear as if this tab has been activated.  I already tried to search for the tab and call `$("myTabs").tabs('selected',index);` but this has given me no results.
Thanks, hope I was not confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I just found the solution under related.   [It is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162148/jquery-tabs-selecting-specific-tab)