# Auto focus on a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set auto focus on a tab when page loads, but I can't make it work. I have created a fiddle, and as you can see in the code, I am trying to set focus on the tab with `class="test`
Can anyone see what I do wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/qL2W4/2391/

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">rr</a></li>
      <li class="test"><a href="#">gg</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">mm</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$("#mydiv").tabs();
$("#mydiv").find(".test").focus();
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162148/jquery-tabs-selecting-specific-tab

Comment: post code AND fiddle please and make the fiddle a link

Comment: Also, to select onload, you can use the options: $("#mydiv").tabs({active:1}); see: https://jsfiddle.net/f18n54z7/

Comment: you can't set focus to li element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `selected` option for this:

```
$("#mydiv").tabs({ selected: 1 });
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL2W4/2393/)

If you want it to work based on the `li` with a specific class you can do it by getting the index of the `li` with the selected class and passing it into the tabs options:

```
var selected = $(".test").index();

$("#mydiv").tabs({ selected: selected });
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL2W4/2397/)

Answer (score 1):

Try next :

```
$("#mydiv").tabs();
$("#mydiv").find(".test a").trigger("click");
```

Or, if you need only switch tab - use active property:

```
$("#mydiv").tabs();
$("#mydiv").tabs({
    active:1
});
```

p.s. in my opinion second method is better, if you not need to emit click event for something other.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply simulate a click:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">rr</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="test">gg</a></li> <!-- NOTE CHANGE -->
    <li><a href="#">mm</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#mydiv").tabs();
  $('.test').click();
});
```